# Shuffling SQLAlchemy results?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

The code in question:

```
 random_items = random.shuffle(Item.query.all())[20:30]
```

It's in a Flask/SQLAlchemy app.`Item` is the model.

That's what I'm doing right now and it works but I foresee a disaster when I start using a real dataset.

How do I do this properly?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure of your concern.  Is it that you'll be returning a large dataset, so large lists will be manipulated in memory?

If so, you can do it within the SQL statement if you're not overly worried about portability; i.e., if you are using MySQL, you can do:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import func
Item.query.order_by(func.rand()).offset(20).limit(10).all()
```

Or, in PostgreSQL:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import func
Item.query.order_by(func.random()).offset(20).limit(10).all()
```

Other databases have similar mechanisms, so the function called would depend on what you're targeting.  And of course, if you are trying to write a general purpose app that can run on any of SQLAlchemy's backends, you might need to stick with the example provided.

Comment: Thank you, yes my concern was that I'd have a huge list in memory and the app would just die (it did).

Now, I can get random items. :) Thanks

Comment: does this work with queries that contain joins ? it seems to do nothing for me.

Comment: Why not include path to import `func` from? I mean, it's just a line of code and it definitely worth mentioning it. It should be `from  sqlalchemy.sql.expression import func`